# javascript Error: 'NAD197005601' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am breaking my head with a javascript error that I am getting. I am trying to create a modal Popup using javascript. The javascript code that I am using is:

```js
function OpenModalDialogCredit(RRID, SLA_Bucket, AccountNum) {
    var vReturnValue;
    var AccountNo = new String();
    AccountNo = AccountNum.toString();
    var url = "RR_Txn_Detail.aspx?RRID=" + RRID + "BucketID=" + SLA_Bucket +
        "AccNum=" & AccountNum;
    if(url != null) {
        vReturnValue = window.showModalDialog(
            "Risk_Report_Weekly_Txn_Detail.aspx?RRID=" + RRID +
            "&BucketID=" +
            SLA_Bucket + "&AccNum=" + AccountNum + "&DtCt=" + 2, '',
            'dialogWidth:800px,dialogHeight:1200px,scroll:1,center:yes;unadorned:yes',
            'screenx=100', 'screeny=100');
    } else {
        alert("No URL passed to open");
    }
}
```

The above code works when AccountNum is a Number but when AccountNum has letters and Numbers, I get an error saying: SCRIPT5009: 'NAD197005601' is undefined. Now 'NAD197005601'is the AccountNum parameter that is passed into the function but for some reason it says its undefined.

Please help me.

thanks

Comment: Don't use `.toString()`

Comment: Are you sure you're not mixing up Java and JavaScript here - the `new String()` and `.toString()`? Why create AccountNo anyway when you don't ever use it?

Comment: `NAD197005601` is out of this function's scope. Error messages usually point out to the row where error happened. You should find and add all  relative code to the question.

Comment: Sorry, the ToString was a mistake, I took that code out. NAD197005601 is the AccountNum being passed into the function. Even when I hover over a row, it shows javascript:OpenModalDialogCredit(10, 37, NAD197005601). When the AccountNum doesnt contain letters, it works, but when it does contain letters, then I get the error.

Comment: OK - are you trying to pass it in as a string without quoting it then? i.e. `OpenModalDialogCredit(10, 37, NAD197005601)`? You probably want `OpenModalDialogCredit(10, 37, 'NAD197005601')` with single or double quotes around the account number.

Comment: @Rup You probably want to add that as an answer, as it looks to be the solution

Comment: @SimonHalsey :-) Thanks - I left it as a comment because it was still slightly speculative and I didn't want to have to write about escaping etc. that I'd need to do for an answer, but thanks for twisting my arm to do it, I'm getting lazy not actually answering questions nowadays.

Comment: `"AccNum=" & AccountNum;` seems to use the wrong operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments you posted you're seeing

```
javascript:OpenModalDialogCredit(10, 37, NAD197005601)
```

presumably for an on-page URL. The problem here is that you haven't quoted the value you're passing in, which means that JavaScript is treating it as a variable not a string value. You need to use (or to generate in your ASP.NET) instead:

```
javascript:OpenModalDialogCredit(10, 37, 'NAD197005601')
```

using either single or double quotes.

If you're using simple alphanumeric values then you can just add the quote characters to either end, but if there's any possibility of other characters (especially if this is user-provided input) then you need to escape the value correctly instead. This is where it gets slightly complicated: what you're actually writing to the page is a quoted string within an HTML attribute so you have a choice of whether to use the JavaScript-provided or HTML-provided escaping for special characters, but you'll need to escape against the value being interpreted as things like JavaScript's `\` string escapes (`\n`, etc.) first either way. And you definitely need to escape any `'` characters in the string to avoid JavaScript interpreting them as end-of-string-value markers allowing script injection. Off the top of my head you'll therefore need to replace

- `\` with `\\`
- `'` with `\'`

in that order before emitting the string from C# into HTML. I'm not, alas, aware of any libraries that'll do this for you.

If you have jQuery on the page then you could do something else, e.g. you could emit the three values as data attributes in HTML (on this, or on an appropriate parent element) and then write script to bind click events to look those up from the correct elements and then make the call. This would allow you to write your values as HTML attributes only, saving some escaping (but not all escaping!) and perhaps allowing you to use ASP.NET's tag generation code to just get that right. But if you're not comfortable with JavaScript yet that might be a bit ambitious.